# Google Scholar paper losing citations

Tags: citations, google-scholar

One of my papers on Google scholar used to have 5 citations. It later went down to 4 and is now on 3. My other papers are monotonically increasing. But I've had this one paper that seems to have lost 2. What might be some reasons for this? Assuming Google Scholar did some checks and found some of them didn't meet certain criteria, just curious what those might be.

Comment: " Assuming Google Scholar did some checks and found some of them didn't meet certain criteria"
Your assumption is wrong. Google Scholar is not a reference tracker. It just tracks what is available online, barely performing any check. 
If you really want to use a proprietary commercial tool (like google), you can use https://www.scopus.com/freelookup/form/author.uri

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happened a couple of times to me, mostly because of duplicates: GS had the same paper indexed twice, which lead to duplicate citations for some of my papers. The duplicate entry was removed at some point, and with it the duplicate citations.

In another case, a paper published informally online was removed from the website, and then also from GS, which lead to citations to my papers being removed as well.

Both cases could be formulated as a "criterion" that Google validates in some internal "check" (no duplicates, online-only resources have to be permanent).